# How to distinguish actual inApp and sandbox inApp?

Tags: android, in-app

In the following code while verifying inApp receipt on Apple we receive a status code 21007 which indicates this is a receipt of a Sandbox inApp and then we test it with Sandbox URL.

```
receipt_dict = json.loads(receipt)
request_data = json.dumps({"receipt-data": receipt_dict["Payload"]})

request = urllib2.Request(url=INAPP_URL_APPLE, data=request_data) 
request.add_header("Content-Type",'application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

response_json = response.read()

if response.getcode() == 200 and json.loads(response_json)["status"] == 21007:
    # if receipt is a Sandbox, test it with Sandbox URL
    response = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url=INAPP_URL_APPLE_SANDBOX, data=request_data))
    response_json = response.read()
    our_response['platform'] = IOS_SANDBOX
```

I want to know is there any way to distinguish Actual and Sandbox InApps on Android?